# Salutation/Professional Addressing "Dy GM", what does it mean?

Tags: subcontinental-english, salutations

Found the addressing "Dy GM" in New Delhi area in the IT domain.

What does it mean?

Comment: Interesting question but easily answerable by a quick google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means **Deputy General Manager**, also abbreviated as *DGM*

Citing sources, as requested.

> Dy. is an abbreviation for Deputy. Please see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dy) Wikipedia link.

Also, GM is an abbreviation for General Manager. Please see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_manager) Wikipedia link.

I work in IT industry, and in my company, we have positions like AGM (Associate General Manager), DGM (Deputy General Manager), GM (General Manager).

Comment: Looks like a good answer, do you have a source?